# Can Web Parts in Sharepoint be moved outside of edit mode using drag & drop?

Tags: sharepoint, drag-and-drop, web-parts

I'm wondering if anyone has implemented an iGoogle/netvibes drag&drop interface in the normal view mode of a Sharepoint 2007 Web Part page?  I would preferably want to use the drag & drop functionality that already exists in the edit mode if possible since this comes with Sharepoint, but I want this to be available in the normal view mode of the page, not just in edit mode.

I've looked around the net for this but can't find anyone who has done this.  I tried a quick test using jQuery but the markup of the page by default makes it difficult to implement with its table based layout.

I've also seen that there's a [table cell sorting](http://normankosmal.com/wordpress/?p=25) implemented with YUI that might be usable for this but I haven't tried it out.

So, any tips would be greatly appreciated if anyone has any experience with this!

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint stores the details of where a web part is on the page in it's database. When you move the web part around in edit mode you're changing it's `Zone` property value in the content database. So if you were able to drag and drop the HTML for the web part you'd also need a way to update the database to let SharePoint know its new position next time the page loads.

I guess this is possible using AJAX to make a call to the server to update the web part's zone but I haven't seen this done anywhere.